# Java DefaultHTTPClient automatically handle cookies

Tags: java, cookies, httpclient

I have a piece of code using the DefaultHttpClient and it makes a post request to login to a website.

However subsequent requests appear to have forgotten the fact im signed in.

How do i turn on automatic cookie handling of the DefaultHttpClient I am using?

Cheers,

Andy

Comment: Do you mean the class from Apache http client 4.x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make shure to use the same `DefaultHttpClient` for every request.